# controlling LEDs, few pin outputs lots of LEDs

Tags: led

We need to control many leds, about 40 with arduino (UNO) and we need some remain turned on and other off at the same time. Muted or pinned vary constantly. 
What should I use to do this, I have several Multiplexers CD4051 but with these I can just light a LED at a time.

I do some calculation and then need to turn LEDs 1,2,5,7 and need to be pinned to the following calculation. In the following calculation I need to turn leds 4, 5, 10, 12 pinned and need to follow. What I need is something like that

With the multiplexer I can turn the LEDs I need and with minimal delay and it seems they are apprehended while, but I want to know if there is another alternative to do so

Comment: Do they need to *be* lit constantly or do they need to *appear* lit constantly?

Comment: Well, I do some calculation and then need to turn leds 1,2,5,7 
and need to be pinned to the following calculation. 
In the following calculation I need to turn leds 4, 5, 10, 12 
pinned and need to follow. 
What I need is something like that

Comment: Alright, but that wasn't what the question was asking.

Comment: Well, I edit my question, it was bad explained

Comment: What my question was asking, rather.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not good. It would be perfect if they be lit constantly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14685/discussion-between-chofer-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

Answer (score 3):

The most common technique for doing this is called ["multiplexing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexed_display). You arrange the 40 LEDs into 8 "columns" and 5 "rows" with common anodes and cathodes, and then you switch the columns or rows on or off individually, activating only the LEDs you want lit for that column or row. If done quickly enough it appears to the human eye that the LEDs are always lit due to [persistence of vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_vision). Note that the *physical* display does not need to be a rectangle; this is simply the *logical* arrangement used in order to simplify the circuit.

[image: LED multiplexing demonstration]

*(note that the cathode side of the above image is wrong; the cathode needs to be **low** when you want the LED to light)*

[(source)](http://www.franksworkshop.com.au/Electronics/RGB/RGB.htm)

A naive implementation with 8 columns and 5 rows would use 13 pins to connect them all. However, since you don't need more than one column at a time what you can do is use a [74HC138/238](http://www.ti.com/product/cd74hct138) to use 3 inputs to control which of the 8 columns you want to activate. This drops the number of required pins to 8, which is low enough for anything larger than a ATtinyX5. Use of a 74HC595 for the 8 pins further drops the required MCU pins to 3, which is low enough for even a ATtiny4/5/9/10, but the timing is harder to get right due to the shift register.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NeoPixels](https://www.adafruit.com/category/168). Make sure to check out the datasheet, as a single Arduino Uno might not be able to provide the required current.